# MySQL database with thousands of tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I'm building a database in MySQL which contains approximately 20,000 tables, one for each human gene, where each gene's table has a single column listing the alternative names (synonyms) for this gene found in the literature, and often times there's no logic to these synonyms and they exist purely for historical reasons.

First off, is there a better way to set up this database with fewer tables?

The problem is that each gene has a variable number of alternative names, so it's not like I can make one big table with each row corresponding to a gene and a set number of columns.  And even if each gene had the same number of alternative names, any particular column would basically be meaningless, since, for example, there would be no relationship between the synonym in column 1 for gene 1 and the synonym in column 1 for gene 2.

What exactly is bad about having thousands of tables in MySQL?

I could potentially break the database up into 23 databases (one for each chromosome), or something like that, and then each database would only have ~900 tables, would something like that be better?

I almost feel like maybe MySQL (a relational database) is the wrong tool for the job.  If that's the case, what would be a better database paradigm?

Comment: I would create one "gene" table and then have another table "alternates" with the id of the gene as a foreign key.

Comment: @Jaime do you mean one global "alternates" table for all genes?  And then use the foreign key for a particular gene to look up its associated synonyms in this "alternates" table?

Comment: And one table for chromosomes.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, what would be the purpose of the chromosomes table?

Comment: @Thoth it appears you've understood Jaime's suggestion correctly; yes, only two tables required in total.

Comment: @Thoth the `genes` table would have a foreign key to `chromosomes` table.

Comment: Something like that :-) However - Most important is the first comment of Jaime.

Comment: Aren't they 'alleles'?

Comment: @Strawberry do you mean instead of variants?  I think allele refers to the entire gene, while variant refers to the specific change that happens within the gene to make it different.

Comment: I see. Well, either way 2 tables sounds more sensible than 20,000!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20,000 tables is a lot of tables. There's nothing necessarily "bad" about having 20,000 tables, if you actually have a need 20,000 tables.  We run with innodb_file_per_table, so that's a whole slew of files, and we'd potentially running up against some limits in MySQL (`innodb_open_files`, `open_files_limit`, `table_cache_open`) which are in turn limited by the OS `ulimit`.

Add to that the potential difficulty managing a large number of *identical* tables. If I need to add a column, I'd be needing to add that column to 20,000 tables. That's 20,000 ALTER TABLE statements. And if I miss some tables, the tables won't be identical anymore. I just don't want to go there, if I can help it.

I'd propose and consider a different design.

As a first cut, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE gene_synonym
( gene           VARCHAR(64) 
, synonym        VARCHAR(255)
, PRIMARY KEY (gene, synonym)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

To add a synonym for a gene, rather than inserting a value into a single column of a particular table:

```
INSERT INTO gene_synonym (gene, synonym) VALUES ('alzwhatever','iforgot');
```

And the querying, instead of figuring out which of the 20,000 tables to be queries, we would query just *one* table and include a condition on `gene` column:

```
SELECT gs.synonym 
  FROM gene_synonym gs
 WHERE gs.gene = 'alzwhatever'
 ORDER BY gs.synonym
```

The `WHERE` clause makes it so we can view a subset of the one big table, the set returned will emulate one of the currently individual tables.

And if I needed to search for a synonym, I could query just this one table:

```
SELECT gs.gene
  FROM gene_synonym gs
 WHERE gs.synonym = 'iforgot'
```

To do that same search with 20,000 tables, I would need 20,000 different SELECTs, one for each each of the 20,000 tables.

I just took a swag at the datatypes. Since MySQL has a limit of 64 characters for a table name, I limited the `gene` column to 64 characters.

We could populate the gene column with the names of the tables in the current design.

However, what this table can't emulate is an empty table, a gene that doesn't have any synonyms. (Or maybe our design would be for the name of the gene to be a synonym of itself, so we'd have a row  `('alzwhatever','alzwhatever')`

Either case, we'd likely also want to add a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE gene
( gene           VARCHAR(64) 
, PRIMARY KEY (gene)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

This is the table that would have the 20,000 rows, one row for each of the tables in your current design.

Further, we can add a foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE gene_synonym 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_gene_synonym_gene (gene) REFERENCES gene (gene)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
;
```

This design is much more in keeping with normative pattern for relational databases.

This isn't to say that other designs are "bad". Just this design would be more typical.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer!  I had a couple of questions, first, what is the significance of the `gs` in your 3rd and 4th blocks of code?  It doesn't seem to do anything and I can leave it off and everything appears to work the same.  Second, could you explain your last block of code with the foreign key constraint?  What is the operational utility of adding this?  Thanks.

Comment: In the queries, the `gs` is a short table alias assigned to the table reference. In this case, the alias isn't required. In other more complicated queries we do need to introduce aliases. But we qualify *all* column references, and using short table aliases is a valid pattern we're very familiar with. That same pattern just carries over to simpler queries even where it's not specifically required.  A foreign key constraint is a mechanism for ensuring consistency. It doesn't allow a values to be assigned to the `gene` column in the `gene_synonym` table that don't appear in the `gene` table.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a synonym table.  *One* such table:

```
create table geneSynonyms (
    geneSynonymId int auto_increment primary key,
    geneId int not null,
    synonym varchar(255),
    constraint fk_geneSynonyms_geneId foreign key (geneId) references genes(geneId),
    constraint unq_geneSynonyms_synonym unique (synonym)  -- I assume this is unique
);
```

Then, you have one row for each synonym for all the genes in a single table.

What is bad about having thousands of tables?  Here are a few things:

- The data storage is very inefficient.  The minimum space occupied by a table is a data page.  If you don't fill the page you are wasting space.
- By wasting space, you end up filling the page cache with nearly empty pages.  This means less data fits into memory, which adversely affects performance.
- Your queries are hard-wired to the table being accessed.  You cannot write generic code for multiple genes.
- You cannot make changes to your data structure, easily.
- You cannot validate data, by having rules that say "a synonym needs to be unique across all genes".
- You cannot readily find the gene that a synonym refers to.
- Improving performance by, say, adding indexes or partitioning the data is a nightmare.